# Problemas ao instalar o Sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite3

Estou enfrentando esse problema ao dar o comando npm install, poderiam me ajudar?

Abaixo o código de erro:

```
➜  Node.js e Tokens git:(master) ✗ npm install
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.14.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@3.0.8: versions < v5.0.0 do not handle NUL in passwords properly
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3310100/sqlite3.c
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@16.13.1 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/rafaelribeiro/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: -: command not found
npm ERR! /bin/sh: python: command not found
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3310100/sqlite3.c] Error 127
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-darwin-arm64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/rafaelribeiro/Desktop/Mesa - MacBook Pro de Rafael/Rafael/Cursos/Alura/Node.js e Tokens/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rafaelribeiro/.npm/_logs/2022-08-08T18_43_37_687Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score -1):

Ele diz ai nas primeiras linhas que seu npm esta desatualizado, vê a versão dele e tenta atualizar, depois ele diz para executar um comando "sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build". Vai lendo os erros e concertando de pouco em pouco que vai rodar. Pois vc tem que atualizar ou então instalar algumas coisas e ele diz todas as coisas que precisa. Vai atualizando as coisas que ele e tentando dar o npm install novamente